# How do you enable hibernate.generate_statistics with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot with Java config. How do I enable hibernate.generate_statistics? I already do have:

> logging.level.org.hibernate.stat: INFO

So I tried adding the following config props, and none of these worked:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.properties.generate_statistics: true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.properties.generate-statistics: true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.generate-statistics: true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.generate_statistics: true
>
> hibernate.generate-statistics: true
>
> hibernate.generate_statistics: true

The only thing that did work was adding:

> -Dhibernate.generate_statistics=true

to the command line. However, for my use case, I prefer to configure this within the Java application itself or properties file in its JAR, not externally on the command line.

Another solution I see is I can also add a "hibernate.properties" file to my classpath, with the contents

> hibernate.generate_statistics=true

And that does indeed work. But is it ideal?

Comment: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Try `jpa.properties.hibernate.generateStatistics: true`

Answer (score 12):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), to set a native property on the JPA provider, you can use:

```
spring.jpa.properties.*= ...
```

So for `hibernate.generate_statistics`, use:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Comment: Additionally make sure logging is enabled for hibernate. E.g: `logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO`